# Map withDefault of an empty ListBuffer in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, mutable

I'm trying to create a mutable `Map` with a default that creates a new `ListBuffer` when an element is requested that is not already in the map. However, while the new map is returned as the default it does not remain in the map. Maybe this is just how it works, I thought, but when I tested it with an `Int` rather than a `ListBuffer` it did exactly as I wanted. Here's some code to explain what I mean - what am I doing wrong?

First, here it is working with a `Map[Int]`:

```
scala> val a = collection.mutable.Map(1 -> 1).withDefault(i => 0)
a: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)

scala> a(1) += 1 // adding to an existing element works as expected

scala> a
res48: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> a(2) += 1 // what about adding to a non-existing element?

scala> a // the new element has been added to the map
res50: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 1)
```

Now with a `Map[ListBuffer[Int]]`:

```
scala> val b = collection.mutable.Map(1 -> collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]()).withDefault(i => collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Int])
b: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = Map(1 -> ListBuffer())

scala> b(1) += 1 // appending to an existing element works as expected
res51: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1)

scala> b
res52: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = Map(1 -> ListBuffer(1))

scala> b(2) += 1 // but appending to a non-existing element...
res53: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1)

scala> b // leaves the map unchanged
res54: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = Map(1 -> ListBuffer(1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is this:

In the first case `a(2)` is an `Int`. Since `Int` doesn't have a `+=` method, `a(2) += 1` is equivalent `a(2) = a(2) + 1` and so to `a.update(2, a(2) + 1)`. The `update` actually changes the map.

But `ListBuffer[Int]` *does* have a `+=` method, so your call is `a(2).+=(1)`, and you don't set `a(2)` to anything!

Comment: Great, that makes sense - so how can I fix it? Do I need to do it over three lines, getting the element, appending to it, then setting it back? Because I'd rather avoid that if possible!

Comment: I suppose I can do map(i) = map(i) += 5 but it looks pretty crappy.

Comment: Yes, I think so (of course, you can always extract this into a nice helper method).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getOrElseUpdate(key: A, op: => B)` where you could just create a new instance of ListBuffer, when the key is not present.

E.g.

```
val m = collection.mutable.Map[Int, ListBuffer[Int]]()
m.getOrElseUpdate(1, ListBuffer()) += 1
```

Comment: +1 because while this may be a little irritating and long-winded to write, the *intent* is a lot clearer.